Laravel symlink symbolic link to storage not working in production - shared hosting
I have deployed Laravel 10 to Siteground. I placed the contents of Laravel's public folder directly inside public_html, and created a separate folder within public_html for the rest of Laravel's directory structure. As a result, the storage folder (which is a symlink) resides inside public_html. However, all my images uploaded to Laravel/storage/app/public are not visible on the website. I have tried recreating the symlink via SSH using the ln -s Linux script. The symlink appears to be there, but I still can't view the images on the website. I have also attempted to modify the .env(APP_URL) or .env(APP_STORAGE_PATH) and filesystem files, but to no avail. What could I be doing wrong?
Here's what I've tried so far:

Connecting to the server via SSH and running ln -s to link storage/app/public with public_html/storage. This seems to work as I can see the symbolic link, but I still can't view the images on the website.
Modifying the .env(APP_URL) or .env(APP_STORAGE_PATH) and filesystem files, but this doesn't seem to have any effect.

I'm running out of ideas. Can anyone provide some guidance?

On an Apache web server, you might need to enable the option FollowSymLinks, resp. rather the safer SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,  https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#options However, what SteJ stated in their answer, still stands - probably not really a good idea to begin with. Can you explain why you want to use this kind of setup to begin with?

This is not advisable. Your public_html directory will be what the web server points to, meaning that anyone can potentially access all the Laravel code, potentially including your .env file which is a common point of attack as it may contain sensitive API keys and database credentials.
I am unfamiliar with the host you are referring to, but I would strongly recommend reaching out to their support and check with them if you are able to change the document root for the web server and maintain the standard Laravel file structure in order to protect the files you need to keep away from prying eyes.

Symbolic links like paths relative to link or absolute. What should work is first cd public_html, you can delete storage directory if it exists. Then run ln -s ./Laravel/storage/app/public ./storage. Storage directory now should be linked to your private storage, see ls -l.

I had wrongly deployed everything inside public_html, I moved everything outside public_html, only moved inside laravel->public folder, then recreated symlink, verified permission were correct and it worked, problem fixed!
